# Voice Changer in Realtime GSM Phone Call

Tags: audio, calls, gsm, java

hello I was wondering whether it would be possible to apply voice changer on GSM Phone call in realtime?

If possible, then I'm thinking of using a voice changer mechanism to secure the voice data before being transmitted to the receiver.

Comment: There are any number of voice changer apps available in the Play Store.  They may or may not be any good.

Comment: yes, and I've tried several existing applications but haven't found one that works in realtime. Most app works by recording the sound first and then selecting the sound to be sent when a phone call is in progress. This is not what I need.